# Angularjs - ng-include not loading the include template (no visible errors)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to include various html templates into a single div on the page when clicking on corresponding links (I am open to better ideas that would allow me to style links as icons)..

I am not sure why ng-include is not doing anything

Html file

```
    <div ng-controller="loadCtrl">

        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="block in blocks">

                    <a href="#" ng-model="block">
                        {{block.name}} - {{block.ctrl}}
                    </a>

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div ng-include="block.ctrl"></div> 

    </div>
```

js controller

```
    app.controller('loadCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.pyctrl = base_data + 'blocks.json';
        $scope.blocks = [];

        $scope.LoadBlocks = function(data, status){
            $scope.blocks = data;
        }

        $scope.fetch = function(){
            $http.get($scope.pyctrl).success($scope.LoadBlocks,console.log("Ok"));
        }

        $scope.fetch();

    });
```

json file

```
    [
        {
            "name": "block 1",
            "ctrl": "dir1/dir2/template1.html"
        },
        {
            "name": "block 2",
            "ctrl": "dir1/dir2/template2.html"
        },
        {
            "name": "block 3",
            "ctrl": "dir1/dir2/template3.html"
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted to keep the `ng-include` inside the `ng-repeat` loop (the `li` element).

---

**Update**: If you want to save a value in `block` when you click on a link, then instead of using `ng-model="block"`, use `ng-click="selectedBlock(block")` to call a function on the scope which does this.

```js
    $scope.block = null;
    $scope.selectBlock = function(block){
        $scope.block = block;
    }
```

Comment: I don't want that. That loads all my templates automatically. I am trying to adapt angular documentation example from here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude just by changing option list to links

Comment: How can I verify that ng-click event is firing.. because nothing is happening when I click in any shape or form?

Comment: No matter how I spin this I can't seem to get it to work. If selected block is outside the loop I can't save it. I really don't want to be a pain, but could you maybe help me with the function on the scope? I am not understanding the ng-click I guess. If I have to use the ng-repeat in a separate div (in which I am loading templates) how could I filter by selected link only?

Comment: @PersistentNewbie The problem was that `selectedBlock` was being created in the `ng-repeat`'s scope and was not accessible outside. Updated the answer to use a function on the controller to do it instead.